# Working on raspberry pi zero. Showing errors. While compiling the opencv i used make ~j4 instead of make. Is it the reason?

Tags: compiler-errors

While compiling the opencv on my raspberry pi zero I used (make ~j4) instead of (make). Then it's showing problems.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the error that you are getting? It looks like the image that you posted only has warnings. Also try `make -j4` instead of `make ~j4`

Comment: I'm getting this warning...